# Modifying an image dynamically doesn't update the image on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this code in my build:

```
XFile? file;
...
body: Container(
    color: Colors.black,
    child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => editPhoto(),
                child: Image.file(File(file!.path))), //here is the line with problems
          ),
        ),
      )
```

With my editPhoto() method, I modify the file whose path is read in my Image.file, but in my screen I still see the old image before the edit. Now, I know for sure that the file has effectively changed because in another part of my code I can see the changes, so the problem is that Image.file doesn't update. How can I solve?

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your issue, but have you tried calling setState after the editPhoto method?